# Produce handouts of slidify or Rpres HTML5 presentations

Tags: html, r, rstudio, slidify

I would like to give my audience handouts of my HTML5 presentation created by slidify or Rstudio's R presentations. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using Google Chrome's print-to-pdf feature. It works great unless you are using complex HTML directives in your deck. With RStudio pres, you can also use the pdf converter that ships with RevealJS. Check out RevealJS github repo to find links to it.

Answer (score 2):

1) Install the software `pandoc`:
http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html

2) Install the stoftware `MikTex` (Windows):
http://miktex.org/download

3) Install the R package `knitr`

```
install.packages("knitr")
```

4) The following only worked after I restarted my PC (Windows)

```
# Load packages
library("knitr")

# Check if pandoc is found on your system
system("pandoc -v")

# Set working directory, e.g.: 
# setwd("C:/r_files")

# Convert mark-up file
pandoc('p4.Rpres', format='latex') # PDF
pandoc('p4.Rpres', format='docx') # DOCX
```

During the execution of the latter command multiple pop-ups were shown saying that MikTex needs to install specfic add-ons to process the command. You have to confirm this to proceed.

For more details see: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/pandoc/

Comment: Oddly, that turns my Rpres into a straight letter-format document, and the images are shot to heck.  Hrm.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use (Awesome Screenshot) is a browser plugin (fire fox, chrome) which takes an images of the browser and creates a .jpg or.png file of the image, also if you really want to make it into a .pdf import the image into photoshop and safe it as a.pdf

hope I answer your question?