# Rpres HTML5 presentation "Save As PDF" (Google Chrome) displays incorrectly

Tags: html, r, google-chrome, pdf, rstudio

I am trying to save the Rpres HTML5 presentation ([a new feature of Rstudio](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/presentations/overview)) as PDF document, which will serve as a presentation handout (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844168/produce-handouts-of-slidify-or-rpres-html5-presentations) )

The problem is that the output looks messed up in the pdf, even for the basic presentation example supplied with the RStudio.

How to recreate the problem - copy this to new .Rpres file from within RStudio, or just open new `File -> New File ->  R Presentation`:

````
test
========================================================
author: 
date: 

First Slide
========================================================

For more details on authoring R presentations click the
**Help** button on the toolbar.

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

Slide With Code
========================================================

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

Slide With Plot
========================================================

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

Within RStudio, click `Preview -> View in Browser`
Within Google Chrome, `right-click -> Print...` will produce [the following messy pdf](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12XCguHoMesCPJ8fNVTPJ-FW3_4pd6WwQT7NaYOrVzvM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the moment, RStudio doesn't come with a print CSS for the Rpresentations. [As per RStudio support reply here](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/4676-rpres-presentation-save-as-pdf-google-chrome-displays-incorrectly), they are looking to add the feature to save as PDF directly into RStudio. In the meantime, [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) is the way to go.

**EDIT May 12, 2014:**

PDF production of presentations has in the meantime been implemented in RStudio. You can get nice PDF in landscape format with controls to navigate between slides. [Download preview version 0.98.836 or higher from here](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/preview). Then click:

`File -> New File -> R Markdown -> Presentation -> Default Output Format = PDF (Beamer)`

[image]

Comment: On Rstudio 0.98.507 I dont see the path you write. I only see: File -> New File -> R Markdown... which opens an Rmarkdown document, or maybe you meant that I write: "Default Output Format = PDF (Beamer)" somewhere in the document?

Comment: @RasmusLarsen, download preview version (right now 0.98.836). I edited the answer.

Comment: The ioslides formatting is distinctly different from that of the default R Presentation, and pasting from one to the other generates all sorts of errors. Is there a way to print existing HTML5 files generated from Rpres scripts to a pdf in such a way as to not have a weird muddled pdf?

Comment: RStudio version 0.98.1028 FYI

Comment: @jebyrnes, I suggest that you create a new SO question and possibly link to this one

Answer (score 3):

You can use RStudio to open the corresponding .md file, of course you have to Preview your .Rpres before to generate the .md file. Then click the Preview button to view the .md file and open it in a browser. Finally, it can be printed as hand-outs.

Comment: RStudio now has the new built-in presentation-to-PDF functionality, see edit to my answer.

Comment: This didn't work for me very well (although it's way better than trying to print directly from the RPres). There are problems with styles and css.